# What are the practical examples of Semidecidable problems? Is NP problem a semidecidable problem?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, np-complete, p-vs-np

I am going through a Turing machine topic. I know about decidable, semi decidable, and decidable problems. But honestly speaking, I did not get any practical examples of Semidecidable problems. Can you please share some examples or a URL link?  Is the NP problem a semidecidable problem? If yes, then it means that NP-complete problems are Recursive enumerable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just equivalent to the class of RE problems (strictly RE\R).
So one example would be finding whether a Diophantine equation has a solution.

- A program could "solve" this problem by iterating through all possible combinations of variables, and testing them. If a solution exists, the program halts and returns yes. If a solution doesn't, the program does not halt.

Here is a wikipedia link for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_(complexity)

Answer (score 0):

A problem in NP with the answer “yes” can be solved by getting a clever hint followed by a polynomial time verification.

We could solve it very very slowly by enumerating all possible hints.

Which means it is semidecidable, since solving the “yes” cases is enough to be semidecidable.